# How to properly i18n a string

Tags: internationalization, django-templates

This more or less complex phrase to translate in my Django template is:

`This site is owned by "<a href="url">The Company Name</a>" and is maintained by partner organizations.`

Is it as simple as:

`{% trans "This site is owned by "<a href="url">The Company Name</a>" and is maintained by partner organizations." %}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a translation point of view, as long as the translator translates the entire string just like that, you are OK.  By that I mean that they put the href around the company name.

From a technical point of view you might want to check out this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/

```
trans template tag

The {% trans %} template tag translates either a constant string (enclosed in single or double quotes) or variable content:

<title>{% trans "This is the title." %}</title>
<title>{% trans myvar %}</title>
```

So it appears